# How to stop run command line after changed in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cache, command-line, flush

Can anyone help me how to change the content in Magento without using the command line like

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

or

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I always have to run this command after any changes in **Magento 2**.

Answer (score 1):

That's how Magento cache works and if you change anything that Magento caches, you need to clear it. You don't need to run this after modifying any PHP code, though. Check [Magento Cache](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html) to learn more about Magento cache in their dev docs.

If you are debugging or in development, you can disable all cache temporarily but is highly unadvised. For example, if you are working on layouts/pages, disable `layout` cache and `page` cache instead of everything.